# hide div first then toggle checkbox to show and hide same div

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, html

Right now I have it backwards. All the '> are visible and the checkbox's toggle show then hide. not hide then show.

js I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".store_checkbox").click(function() {
    $('[store_id='+$(this).val()+']').toggle();
    }); 
});
```

erb file:

```
<h3>Stores Offered In</h3>
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
    <% for store in Store.all %>
        <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[store_ids][]", store.id, 
@idea.stores.include?(store), :class => "store_checkbox" %> <%= store.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <br />

  <h3>Taxonomies Offered In</h3>
  <% for store in Store.all %>
     <% if store.has_taxonomies? %>
     <div store_id='<%= store.id %>'>
        <h4><%= store.name %></h4>
          <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
            <% for taxonomy in store.taxonomies %>
                <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[taxonomy_ids][]", 
taxonomy.id, @idea.taxonomies.include?(taxonomy) %> <%= taxonomy.name %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to hide the div:

```
'[store_id='+$(this).val()+']' or    <div store_id='<%= store.id %>'> : in erb file
```

then I want to be able to click "store_checkbox" and toggle that div to show and hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".store_checkbox").change(function () {
        $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```